# spring jpa @ManyToOne not generating foreign keys

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

When I generate the tables it generates it ok, but JPA is not generating any FK.

When I tell mysql to show me what it did to create the table it shows the lack of the foreign key constraint. It only generates KEY and it is not adding the foreign key.

mysql> show create table view_display;

> | view_display | CREATE TABLE `view_display` (
>     `dtype` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
>     `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
>     `col` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `row` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `chart_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `view_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
>     `data_source_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>     KEY `FKqllm025dtc51xf38qdr5je52q` (`chart_id`),
>     KEY `FKb1gu01sld2cm281oa88pjq9ia` (`view_id`),
>     KEY `FK2hljr3ohtf3vql7hhvyqbm2mc` (`data_source_id`)
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

**View.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="view")
public class View {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "view_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "view_seq", sequenceName = "view_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name ="is_default",nullable= false,columnDefinition="tinyint(1) default 0")
    private boolean isDefault;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId",insertable=true, updatable= false,nullable=true)
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cvId",insertable=true, updatable= false,nullable=true,unique=true)
    private CV cv;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="view")
    private List<ViewDisplay> viewDisplay;
    // getters and setters....
}
```

**ViewDisplay.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "view_display")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class ViewDisplay {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "view_display_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "view_display_seq", sequenceName = "view_display_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="chartId",insertable=true, updatable= true, nullable = true)
    private Chart chart;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "viewId", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable=false)
    private View view;

    private int col;

    private int row;

    public ViewDisplay() {}

    public ViewDisplay(Long id, Chart chart, View view, int col, int row) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.chart = chart;
        this.view = view;
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
    }
    // getters and setters...



}
```

Comment: The MyISAM storage engine doesn't support foreign keys

Comment: @TahirHussainMir it creates the keys not the FOREIGN KEYS constraint,

Comment: @AndyWilkinson you are right...